# Boostrap 3 data-toggle accordian

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

This is what i have

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible-1">Digital</a>

  <div id="collapsible-1">
        HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages.</a>
  </div>

<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible-2">Radio</a>

  <div id="collapsible-2">
        HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages.</a>
  </div>
```

I use `data-toggle boostrap` to show and hide element, but i have some minor issue, on this way, when pages load the content of collapsable is always visible, even i have to do double click to close the element, and after that is working ok. what do you thinki i have to do, to collapsabe element content to always be hidden on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage):

> Usage
>   The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy lifting:
>
> **.collapse** hides the content
>   .collapse.in shows the content
>   .collapsing is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes

So in short: `<div id="collapsible-1" class='collapse'>`

Comment: Have you added the class 'collapse' to your divs like I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `collapse` class to the div to hide the content by default like this

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible-1">Digital</a>

  <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
        HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages.
  </div>

<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible-2">Radio</a>

  <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
        HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages.
  </div>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VS5q9/)